# Como conectar a minha app feita em RN com uma api local consumindo os dados em post?

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, axios, requisição

Boa dia gente, estou empacado desde ontem e preciso de ajuda. Não consigo conectar o app que estou desenvolvendo a api que está em meu pc.

1° Erro 404
2° Não sei se estou fazendo a requisição da forma correta    ( O meu device está na mesma rede do computador e eu consegui acessar    a API por ele - isso indica que estão se comunicando, o problema de    fato deve ter o código que estou escrevendo ")
3° Por gentileza,    preciso de uma dica de como usar isso com o Async Storage

Código feito para a requisição:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          error: '',
          sucesso: false
        };

        this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
    }


    loginUser() {
        const { email, senha } = this.state;

        this.setState({ error: '', sucesso: true});

        axios.post('http://localhost/api/login',{
            user: {
                email: email,
                senha: senha
            }
        },)
        .then((response) => {
            alert(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        });
    }
```

Abaixo o código do form:

```
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.textLabel}>E-mail</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.input}
                            onChange={(email) => this.setState( user.email )}
                        />

                        <Text style={[styles.textLabel, style = { marginTop: '5%' }]}>Senha</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.input}
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            onChange={(newValue) => this.setState( user.senha )}
                        />

                        <Ripple style={styles.forgottenPw} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PasswordRecovery')}>
                            <Text>
                                Esqueceu a sua senha?
                                </Text>
                        </Ripple>

                        <Button style={styles.btnAcess}
                            onPress={() => this.loginUser()}>
                            <Text style={styles.textBtnAcess}>ENTRAR</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `localhost` vai sempre apontar para a maquina local, no caso do app `localhost` vai ser o proprio device, por isso da 404, o obviamente o seu servidor nao esta rodando no device

O jeito mais facil e apontar para o IP da sua maquina, onde o servidor esta rodando e pronto.

ao inves de `axios.post('http://localhost/api/login'` vai ficar algo como `axios.post('http://192.168.1.10/api/login'`, logico que o IP vai ser outro ai na sua maquina.

#### Simulador

Isso funciona somente no simulador, usar o endereco `10.0.2.2` no lugar do `localhost`, faz com que o os requests para o localhost do simulador sejam  redirecionados para o `localhost` da sua maquina.

Comment: Quando eu coloco o ip do localhost no navegador do meu smartphone consigo enxergar as pastas e acessar a dasbhoard por ele da mesma forma que acesso pelo pc ( Ambos estão na mesma rede )

Comment: ja testou o post para o endereco `http://localhost/api/login` com o `postman` ou similar?

Comment: Já, e funcionou!

Comment: Resolvi, Obrigado. :)

Comment: conta como resolveu por favor

Comment: Usei o caminho absoluto de onde a api está. Ao invés de "http://ip/api/login/". Coloquei "http://ip/folder_do_projeto/public/api/login".